# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "RtMidiIn::RtMidiIn

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors

I'm trying to connect to a MIDI device from an existing program. [RtMidi](https://www.music.mcgill.ca/%7Egary/rtmidi/) is a popular library for this. As I understand, all I should have to do is drop RtMidi.cpp and RtMidi.h in the directory with the rest of the source, and build as usual. I've done so, and added to one of the main classes that get loaded:

```
#include "RtMidi.h"
```

And only this in the constructor:

```
RtMidiIn *midiin = new RtMidiIn();
```

Just to see if that much compiles. But I'm getting the following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "RtMidiIn::RtMidiIn(RtMidi::Api, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      spotify::playback::AudioDecompressorProcess::AudioDecompressorProcess(spotify::playback::AudioSinkChain const&, std::__1::function<std::__1::unique_ptr<spotify::playback::AudioDecompressor, std::__1::default_delete<spotify::playback::AudioDecompressor> > (spotify::tl::span<unsigned char const>)> const&, bool, spotify::playback::PlaybackInstrumentation&, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >) in libplayback.a(audio_decompressor_process.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/acheong/src/spotify/client-web/desktop/shell/build/desktop/Debug/Spotify.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotify normal (in target 'Spotify' from project 'spotify')
```

I found [this thread](https://github.com/thestk/rtmidi/issues/32) which suggested defining `__MACOSX_CORE__`. I tried this in 2 ways. First, using a `#define` right before the include:

```
#define __MACOSX_CORE__
#include "RtMidi.h"
```

Same error. Second, by adding this to the `xcodebuild` command line:

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS='$GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS __MACOSX_CORE__'
```

Same error still. (These are definitely doing *something* though, because when I accidentally tried both the above simultaneously, I got an error that the macro was already defined.)

I'm not super familiar with C++ build chains, so I'm not sure whether I'm just doing something stupid—like, do I need to update some Makefiles or something for the compiler to "see" RtMidi.cpp/h—or is this some kind of compatibility issue as I've read in some threads.

Comment: You'll have to add the RtMidi.cpp file to the Xcode project. Been a while since I used Xcode, but there's bound to be an "add exiting file(s)" (or something similar) around somewhere (maybe on the "Project" menu).

Comment: I don't think the instructions say to ***drop RtMidi.cpp and RtMidi.h in the directory with the rest of the source, and build as usual*** I see this: [https://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/index.html#compiling](https://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/index.html#compiling) and for macos it has `g++ -Wall -D__MACOSX_CORE__ -o midiprobe midiprobe.cpp RtMidi.cpp -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreFoundation`

Comment: ... or add the file to the list of inputs on your xcodebuild command.

Comment: @drescherjm - I might be wrong, but I thought those were instructions to output a dynamically linkable object, which could be another way to do this, but I don't know how. I read in a couple other places that one could simply put RtMidi.cc/h in the project and have it statically linked.

Comment: Almost all C and C++ compilers/linkers work such as they compile/link *only* the files you tell them to compile. There may be some tricks in systems like CMake that scan whole directories, but that's certainly not the default. Other programming languages (like Python) may work very differently.

Comment: Ah, indeed I see alongside the .xcodeproj, CMakeCache.txt, CMakeFiles, CMakeScripts, cmake_install.cmake, etc. and also this is a giant repo, with hundreds of files in deeply nested directories. I'll keep trying things and report back if I find a solution.

Comment: @AdrianMole - Thanks Adrian. I just needed to add the files to my CMakeLists.txt (as I self-answered below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AdrianMole was right—I had to explicitly instruct CMake to build the RtMidi files. I added the files in the relevant CMakeLists.txt under SOURCES:

```
sp_add_sources(TARGET playback
  FOLDER "src"
  ROOT "src"
  SOURCES
    RtMidi.cpp
    RtMidi.h
    audio_buffered_sink.cpp
    audio_buffered_sink.h
    audio_container_format.cpp
    ...
```

And also added this:

```
target_link_libraries(playback PRIVATE "-framework CoreMIDI")
```

Then I was able to include "RtMidi.h" in my existing program, and add the example code, *i.e.*

```
RtMidiIn *midiin = new RtMidiIn();
// Check available ports.
unsigned int nPorts = midiin->getPortCount();
...
```

and have everything build successfully, not even needing the `__MACOSX_CORE__` anywhere.