# Using rtmidi library with c++ on Macos and Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I'm a relative beginner with c++ and coming from windows/linux, i'm using Macos for 1 year
So excuse my ignorance

I have used rtmidi for a while with python, install rtmidi wrapper with pip and just include the header in my python source to include it in my project.
So i want to use it with c++, but i don't figure how i can do the same thing

With Xcode i've made a console project in the folder of rtmidi ( after compiling it with success ) and include in my main.cpp :

```
#include "../../Rtmidi.h"
```

But with the example code i got errors about definitions of the API
like in this post :
[Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "RtMidiIn::RtMidiIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71639351/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-rtmidiinrtmidiin)

I've included Rtmidi.cpp as a file, it solved the warnings but the program didnt work like expected, and i think it would be better to include the folder where the header files and cpp are (RtMidi) but i dont find the place to do that in xcode.

[image: mysetup]

Do i have to use cmake and how or is there another solution for me because the last solution in the post which seems to work is odd for me

### edit:

I tried this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../../RtMidi.h"

int main()
{
    RtMidiOut *midiout = new RtMidiOut();
    std::vector<unsigned char> message;

    // Check available ports.
    unsigned int nPorts = midiout->getPortCount();
    if ( nPorts == 0 ) {
      std::cout << "No ports available!\n";
      goto cleanup;
    }
    // Open first available port.
    midiout->openPort( 0 );

    // Note On: 144, 64, 90
    message[0] = 144;
    message[1] = 64;
    message[2] = 90;
    midiout->sendMessage( &message );

cleanup:
  delete midiout;
return 0;
}
```

and got this error:

```
// It should not be possible to get here because the preprocessor
// definition __RTMIDI_DUMMY__ is automatically defined if no
// API-specific definitions are passed to the compiler. But just in
// case something weird happens, we'll thrown an error.
std::string errorText = "RtMidiOut: no compiled API support found 
... critical error!!";
throw( RtMidiError( errorText, RtMidiError::UNSPECIFIED ) );
```

i think passing API directive : RtMidi::MACOSX_CORE to the compiler may solve the problem but i dont know how to do that on xcode

Comment: "I've included Rtmidi.cpp it solved the warnings but the program didnt work like expected" - So, the problem is probably with your C++ code. Using CMake won't fix incorrect C++ code. Without looking into that code (in form of [mcve]) we cannot help you.

Comment: i forgot to say i just try the default example code with it, and it dont work and the same code compiled with the library works fine
I think i have to find someone who know the use of rtmidi on osx

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem:

First i figure out how to include folder to my project for headers in Xcode, by doing a search in build settings for "search headers"
so i can find RtMidi.h and so on.

Second i have to link CoreMidi CoreAudio & CoreFoundation

And Finally put
#define **MACOSX_CORE**
on top of the RtMidi.h header file